# Kendo Drag and Drop from source to destination and vice versa

Tags: kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-draggable, kendo-droptarget

I have implemented kendo drag drop functionality (drag from source and drop to destination), but now i want to apply the drag and drop in vice versa condition also (drag from destination and drop to source), i.e drag and drop from both. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on what do you refer. Drag from desktop to app?
Maybe Sortable panels? 
Here is example:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/sortable-panels

Or maybe drag and drop between grids?
Here is example:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/various/drag-and-drop-rows-between-two-grids